# How to show the gradient of a composite function $g(z)=f(Az+b)$ is $\nabla g(z)=A^{\top} \nabla f(x)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, scalar-fields

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function (having continuous first and second derivatives). Define $g(z):=f(Az+b)$, $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $$\nabla g(z)=A^{\top} \nabla f(x)$$

---

My try:

I know we can write $\nabla g(z)=\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\nabla f(x)=A^{\top} \nabla f(x)$ but I want to show it using matrix manipulation. Please complete my derivation or comment on that.

$$
\nabla g(z) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial g(z)}{\partial z_1}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial g(z)}{\partial z_n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial z_1}f(x)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_n}f(x)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial z_1}\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1}f(x)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_n}\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial x_n}f(x)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial z_1}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}f(x)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial z_n}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_n}f(x)
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{1}
$$

On the other hand,

$$
x_i=[x]_{i1}=[Az+b]_{i1}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}z_{k1}+[b]_{i1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial z_i}=\frac{\partial [x]_{i1}}{\partial z_{i1}} = a_{ii} \tag{2}
$$

I cannot match $(1)$ using $(2)$. Could you please revise my derivation or complete it?

Comment: I wrote an answer here using Taylor expansions, deriving both first and second derivatives: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3313532/570298

Answer (score 3):

An easier way avoiding these messy calculations is using the characterization $DF(p)(v)=\langle \nabla F(p),v\rangle$, for all $F:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$. Since the total derivative of a linear map is itself, we have $$Dg(z)(v) = Df(Az+b)(Av) = \langle \nabla f(Az+b), Av\rangle =\langle A^\top \nabla f(Az+b), v\rangle.$$Thus $\nabla g(z) = A^\top \nabla f(Az+b)$.

Comment: Can you explain why the first equality holds true? Or prove that for me?

Comment: Nothing to prove, just the regular chain rule.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand why using chain rule we can have $Dg(z)(v) = Df(Az+b)(Av)$?

Comment: Well, $D(G\circ F)(z) = DG(F(z))\circ DF(z)$. Now make $G=f$ and $F(z)=Az+b$.

Comment: And what is $DF(z)$?

Comment: The total derivative of a map $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ is a linear map. See wikipedia for more details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Comment: I understood that $DF(z)=A$ but why $(DG(F(z))\circ DF(z))(v)=(Df(Az+b)\circ A)(v)=Df(Az+b)(Av)$